# getting JSON response from webpage

Tags: java, json, jsonp

I don't know a lot about this area so please excuse me if my question is vague or stupid.

I have a webpage which uses javascript and AJAX to display live data. Every few seconds, a request is made and a JSON response is returned and the data on the webpage is updated.

What I want to do is create a program in Java that will basically capture every response and interpret the data. I have found libraries which handle the JSON format already. However, I don't know how to get the response using Java.

So for example, a live news feed. I would like to log the data as it appears.

Thanks

Comment: You want to do it in Java or JavaScript? The data is returned from server as a result of an AJAX request. So, I hope, you would like to process it in JavaScript

Comment: @Nishant: It's quite common to process JSON responses using other languages, actually.

Comment: I would like to process the data in Java

Comment: @Eric Giguere Yeah, I know. I use GSon extensively. But on a webpage, specially when I make a AJAX request. I like to process there itself. Just wanted to know if @Roger wants it in Java or JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is make an `HTTP GET` request to the page that hosts the JSON.  You can do this by using a Java [HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/).  The one in the link is from Apache Commons but I believe there is actually one built into Java that is relatively straight-forward to use. When you make a request, it will return a result object that you can then use to access the response data and information such as response headers, etc.

Comment: I've tried using the Apache library. Can I just check, do I have to use the URL of the website, or the URL that the script calls (i.e. www.example.com/jsonp/..)? I assume the latter? which means I must manually call HttpGet(..) every few seconds? Cheers

Comment: @Roger, right, you'll have to call the full request url (so including the script) and then you'll also have to call it explicitly every time you want to get the JSON.